# Trouble assigning values in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm trying to create a 2d array in javascript and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here the code I have.

```
var result = [];
var temp = [];
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    temp.push(0);
}
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    result.push(temp);
}
```

So this should create an array of 3x3. Now this should be the code to assign a value to only the value of the second row.

```
result[1][1] = 'red';
```

But it only results in the entire row getting changed.

```
[[0, 'red', 0],
[0, 'red', 0],
[0, 'red', 0]]
```

I tried this on my website, on codepen, even in console and its all the same. I really dont know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you are trying to initialize one 2D array, why do you have two arrays and two separate loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three entries in `result` are references to the exact same `temp` array. Changes to one result in changes to the others because they are quite literally the same thing.

Instead, you'll need to create three separate array. For example:

```
var result = []
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    result[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        result[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! I didn't realise that it would be exactly `temp`. I thought it would just make a copy of it. Thanks!

Comment: @Pulotum You have to keep in mind that `temp` is *not* an array. It is a *reference* to an array in memory.

Comment: By the way, if you ever want to copy an array (not for this case, but for others), you can do so with `var array2 = array1.slice()`

Comment: @NicholasTower Or `array2 = Array.from(array1)` in ES6+.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

`result.push(temp);`

With:

`result.push(temp.slice());`

This will clone the temp so you won't have a reference to one and the same.  temp array. Arrays are passed by reference, so they should be clonned if you prefer an independent copy.